# Are group schemes in Char 0 reduced? (YES)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

A Theorem of Cartier (e.g.  [Mumford](http://books.google.com/books?id=-5weWX_YD6sC&printsec=frontcover&dq=curves+on+an+algebraic+surface&source=bl&ots=1r4O86OtJy&sig=PIH5b5EipbZYJWXrWy77NvltSP4&hl=en&ei=4PjUS9uMKMOC8gbbi_mCDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CBIQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false), Lecture 25) states that every separated, finite type group scheme $G/k$ over a field $k$  of characteristic $0$ is reduced.  Does this result remain valid if we drop the assumption that $G/k$ is separated and of finite type?

Frans Oort (MR0206005) observed that one can use limit formalism to argue that every affine group scheme over $k$ is reduced.

**Edit:** BCnrd pointed out that group schemes over a field are automatically separated.  Furthermore, the proof of Cartier's Theorem in Mumford's book remains valid for a locally Noetherian $k$-group scheme.

Comment: Every gp scheme over field is sep'td: ratl pts are closed immersions, and diag is base change of id. section. Also, conn'd gp lft over field k is f.t. (use geometric conn'dness and pass to kbar), whence smooth for char 0 in lft case. (Pf of Cartier's thm works in lft case over field of char. 0, so this reasoning is silly.) Any *noetherian* gp scheme over fld of char. 0 is formally smooth: completion at 1 is formal gp of finite dim, and Cartier's pf works in formal case (use formal Lie theory w/o smoothness hypothesis!) or use Thm 3.3ff Exp. VII SGA3. Then translate and extend base field. QED

Comment: BCnrd, Im srry t sy tht Im strting to hv pbs rding u! :/

Comment: I posted the comment community-wiki style with vowels added back in!

Comment: By the way, BCnrd, would you prefer that I quote you as BCnrd or Brian Conrad?  

Comment: I find that I enjoy the placement-of-vowels exercise that is left to the reader.  :)

Comment: @Mariano: sorry, I realize it can be a puzzle, and that for those whose native language is not English it can be a problem. But it is better for me that I live within the confines of comment space restrictions, as I will ramble on for too much o/w. A big cause of it sometimes (not always) is that the space counter for comments treats things like \mathbf{Q} as 10 characters when takes up only 1 space in output! Now *that* would be wondrful to fix; not sure how. Hmm, I guess sometimes I should use 2 comment boxes. I enjyd th pzzl dcphrng yr cmmnt, btw. @Harry: please use BCnrd, for consistency. 

Comment: @BCnrd: Alright, I changed it.

Comment: For the record, I have so far very much enjoyed your ramblings! :)

Comment: @jlk: You're right that the argument I gave works in the locally noetherian case.  But it all is moot in view of Perrin's thesis in LRG's answer. 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is yes - *every* group scheme over a field of characterstic zero is reduced: see [Schémas en groupes quasi-compacts sur un corps et groupes henséliens](http://www.math.u-psud.fr/~biblio/numerisation/docs/P_PERRIN-109/pdf/P_PERRIN-109.pdf) (especially Thm. 2.4 in part II and Thm. 1.1 and Cor. 3.9 in part V of the 1st part), and for a summary of the relevant results see 4.2 (in particular 4.2.8) of [Approximation des schémas en groupes, quasi compacts sur un corps](http://archive.numdam.org/article/BSMF_1976__104__323_0.djvu).

Answer (score 8):

BCnrd posted:

> Every group scheme over a field is separated: rational points are closed immersions, and the diagonal is the base change of the identity section. Also, a connected group locally of finite type over field k is of finite type (use geometric connectedness and pass to the algebraic closure of k), whence smoothness follows for characteristic 0 in the locally of finite type case. (The proof of Cartier's theorem works in the locally of finite type case over a field of characteristic 0, so this reasoning is silly.) Any noetherian group scheme over field of characteristic 0 is formally smooth: the completion at 1 is a formal group of finite dimension, and Cartier's proof works in formal case (use formal Lie theory without a smoothness hypothesis!), or use Theorem 3.3ff Exp. VII of SGA3. Then translate and extend base field. QED